# GAS: How to get a vertical panel centered in the screen of a standalone app? (`TypeError: Can not read the "CENTER" property of undefined.`)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm writing my first standalone GAS app! I'm doing it using some code of my spreadsheet scripts. 
I'm reading the capter of [Serge Insas book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783552174). And I found it very good, clarifying to me several concepts that now I understand much better. 
But I have a problem with a vertical panel aligment (in my spreadsheet script, it was automatically alignhed at center). I want the panel to be shown at center (it was been shown by default at left upper corner of the screen. 
I got the panel to be centered, but the `UiApp` wasn't centered. So it was shown that uggly double scroll bar to the user manually center the panel. 
After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533812/how-to-center-elements-google-apps-script-uiapp), I write this code:

```
function doGet() {  
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(1400).setWidth(1800);
  //var _imgCSS = {'position':'relative', 'left':'200PX', 'top':'200PX'}    
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes(_imgCSS)
                 .setHorizontalAlignment(UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
                 .fullPanel.setVerticalAlignment(UiApp.VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
```

But I got an error (in my language): `TypeError: Can not read the "CENTER" property of undefined.`

How to fix that and get a vertical panel centered in the screen of a standalone app in a simple way?

EDIT: I have noticed that if I change the values of this line:

```
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(1400).setWidth(1800);
```

for this

```
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(140).setWidth(180);
```

I didn't notice no change (in the scroll bars). How to expand the app area? (I think this will solve my vertical panel problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define width and height in %, that will solve the scrollbar issue.

Then use a main parent panel like in this code :

```
function doGet() {  
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var main = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes({'background':'beige'}).setWidth('100%').setHeight('100%').setHorizontalAlignment(UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes({'background':'red'}).setWidth('400').setHeight('800');
  var label = app.createLabel('test label');
  app.add(main);
  main.add(panel);
  panel.add(label)
  return app;
}
```

[test here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwrWoweQ8cWvlZyEk8vPwUxsPpGrfG-NkNG9vO8L8MBcLavcibG/exec)

[image]

Comment: Perfect, maybe I just should have read your book some more pages before asking this... But I was eager to see this work! =)

Comment: my pleasure ! Didn't see you for a while ... too busy ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes! But I still try to to program on Saturdays and Sundays. I'm making an app for social purposes. I hope to show you when it is ready. And since now I thank you, because without your help this app probably would not exist! (or would exist only in a far distant future)